# Pandas df.to_latex() output gets truncated

Tags: python, pandas, export

**Problem:** I tried to export a `pandas.DataFrame` to LaTex using [`.to_latex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html).

However, the output for long values (in my case long strings) gets truncated.

**Step to reproduce:**

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(['veryLongString' * i for i in range(1, 5)], dtype='string')
print(df.to_latex())
```

**Output:**

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} &                                                  0 \\
\midrule
0 &                                     veryLongString \\
1 &                       veryLongStringveryLongString \\
2 &         veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongString \\
3 &  veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongStringvery... \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

As you can see, the last row gets truncated (with `...`).
I already tried to use the `col_space` parameter but this does not change the behavior as expected.
It simply shifts the table cells as following:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} &                                                            0 \\
\midrule
0                                                  &                                     veryLongString \\
1                                                  &                       veryLongStringveryLongString \\
2                                                  &         veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongString \\
3                                                  &  veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongStringvery... \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

How do I get the full content of the DataFrame exported to Latex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the [context manager](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html) with a `with` statement to temporarily change the max column width:

```
with pd.option_context("max_colwidth", 1000):
    print (df.to_latex())
```

Output:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} &                                                         0 \\
\midrule
0 &                                            veryLongString \\
1 &                              veryLongStringveryLongString \\
2 &                veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongString \\
3 &  veryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongStringveryLongString \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

This behaviour is also described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6491).

Comment: What a useful alternative to temporarily change this option.

Answer (score 4):

After spending some time trying out other parameters from `to_latex()` as well as other export options, e.g., `to_csv()`, I was sure that this is not a problem of `to_latex()`.

I found the solution in the pandas documentation:

[image]

So the solution is setting this option to `None` to don't restrict the output (globally).

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html